# How to get the contents of last line in tkinter text widget (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, console

I am working on a virtual console, which would use the systems builtin commands and then do the action and display output results on next line in console. This is all working, but how do I get the contents of the last line, and *only* the last line in the tkinter text widget? Thanks in advance. I am working in python 3.
I have treed using `text.get(text.linestart, text.lineend)` To no avail. Have these been deprecated? It spits out an error saying that `AttributeError: 'Text' object has no attribute 'linestart'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply modifiers to the text widget indicies, such as `linestart` and `lineend` as well as adding and subtracting characters. The index after the last character is `"end"`.

Putting that all together, you can get the start of the last line with `"end-1c linestart"`.

Answer (score 0):

Test widget has a see(index) method.
text.see(END) will scroll the text to the last line.

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question. They want to get the contents of the last line, not scroll to it.

Answer (score 0):

To get information from the last line you can use

`text.get("end-1c linestart", "end-1c lineend")`